# How to add column in sql server with column name value is given by case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
PriorityOID Priority    NoOfRestrictedDaysForReporting  AllowBackDatedCompletionForDays SOXReporting    SortOrder   PenaltyFactorPercent    RiskFactor
1   Trifling    NULL    0   NULL    50  105 3
2   Low NULL    0   NULL    40  105 3
3   Medium  NULL    0   NULL    30  105 3
4   High    NULL    0   NULL    20  105 3
5   Critical    NULL    0   NULL    10  110 6
6   Not Available   NULL    0   NULL    60  105 3
7   Super-critical  NULL    NULL    NULL    9   120 9
```

[image: image of my table]

I have to add one another column with name as 'Numbering' and case is when super then 1 when critical then 2 when high then 3 when medium then 4 when low then 5 when trifling then 6 when not available then 7

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it work? This looks like seems like you're just talking about a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Have you tried with case expression in SQL Server if so why it not worked include that in your question by editing the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select
    t.*,
    case priority
        when 'Super'         then 1
        when 'Critical'      then 2
        when 'High'          then 3
        when 'Medium'        then 4
        when 'Low'           then 5
        when 'Trifling'      then 6
        when 'Not Available' then 7
    end numbering
from mytable t
```

If you want to actually store that information in the table, then, as commented by Larnu, a computed column seems like a relevant approach (or a view):

```
alter table mytable 
add numbering as (
    case priority
        when 'Super'         then 1
        when 'Critical'      then 2
        when 'High'          then 3
        when 'Medium'        then 4
        when 'Low'           then 5
        when 'Trifling'      then 6
        when 'Not Available' then 7
    end
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PriorityOID,Priority,NoOfRestrictedDaysForReporting,
AllowBackDatedCompletionForDays, SOXReporting,SortOrder,PenaltyFactorPercent,RiskFactor,
CASE WHEN Priority='super' THEN 1
     WHEN Priority='critical' THEN 2 
     WHEN Priority='high' THEN 3 
     WHEN Priority='medium' THEN 4
     WHEN Priority='low' THEN 5 
     WHEN Priority='trifling ' THEN 6
     when Priority='Not Available' THEN 7 
     else 8....go on..        

     END AS Numbering

Frm YourTableName
```

Note:- You have to use case when then..